# How can I set cmake to look in different places for the headers and libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

The project I'm working on is migrating everything over to cmake, but has a structure for how the library and include files for external libraries are stored. Is there any way to have cmake look in one place for the includes, and another for the library files? We are using 'find_package' to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_package` does exactly what the name suggest, search for a *package*, which usually is a set of headers and library files. The packages you search for may have different structures, but usually the find module search for a specific one, for example /lib for the libraries and /usr/include for the headers.
If you already know where to look for the headers or for the libraries you can set them with

- [`include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/include_directories.html)
- [`link_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/link_directories.html)

It is also possible to set include and link per target with

- [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_include_directories.html)
- [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_link_libraries.html)

Comment: thanks, that is really helpful and seems to have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe;

- [`include_directories(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) for include folders
- [`link_directories(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html) for folders with libraries

There's also the [`target_include_directories(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) if you want more specific control.